# How to access stored data from d3 async calls in document.ready function to pass it to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I was trying to store data from a async call to a variable/object/array outside  the function. I have seen couple of solutions to make calls synchronous, using callbacks etc but none of them works for my scenario. This is what I am trying to do

```
var x = [];
d3.json(url, response){
if(response{
   setInterval(funtion (){
   d3.json(url, response){
   x=response; 
   });
},5000);
}
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log(x);
$.each(x, function(i,val){
  function(val);
});
});
```

Comment: This is a serious race condition and you shouldn't structure your code like this.  You should give up on `document.ready` and just place your code at the end right before then end of the body tag.  Then move your processing on `x` into the `d3.json` callback function (which btw doesn't look like valid code above).

Comment: @Mark I have used a call back function and tried having my x inside d3.json function. I am trying to store data from api constantly after every 5secs then how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make deferred jquery function calls something like this:

```
function test(){
          var defer = $.Deferred();
          setTimeout(function(){console.log("prints 1st");defer.resolve();},1000);
          return defer;
 }
function test2(){
       console.log("prints 2nd");
      return $.when();
 }
test().then(test2).then(function () {
           console.log("prints at the end.");    
 });
```

Here is a working example http://jsbin.com/payitucami/edit?html,console